# trying to run a cronjob and even the very simple one wont work

Tags: php, cron

i am trying to to run this:

`* * * * * lynx http://www.domain.com/cron/updatetest.php`

That should be simple but still it wont work.  now that's really weird because this should work. when i put the address in the browser(the real one) it works perfectly.

Any clue ?

Comment: you need to provide a bit more information on what you've tried, what error if any, what it says in the web server log, etc. As it is now, you're asking people to take a stab in the dark.

Comment: This question is very vague and openended. What have you tried? Which folder is your cron entry in? Have you tried the full path to the lynx executable? Does the cron process have permission to run the file and lynx?

Comment: Also, give wget a try instead of lynx.

Comment: yea you are correct. i didnt give much info but the truth is i am not so savvy with cronjob.

Comment: Have you lynx installed? When you run `lynx http://www.domain.com/cron/updatetest.php` on the command line, does it work as well?

Comment: @jchapa I've so far tried the above, i also tried it without lynx, i tried with absolute path as well - i set the crons premissions to 7/7/7 and nothing

Comment: Which folder are you putting your cronjob into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with cron are usually environment problems. In this case it might be, that lynx doesn't have a terminal to work with. Since you want to just request the page, try

```
* * * * * lynx -dump http://www.domain.com/cron/updatetest.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want to save the requested page instead, use something like

```
* * * * * lynx -dump http://www.domain.com/cron/updatetest.php >/path/to/file.txt
```

See also [`man lynx`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx)

Comment: Thanks for trying it doesnt seem to work.. whats doesnt help is me being clueless - any idea on a good way to start(tutorials) regarding SSH/command line or cronjobs ?

Comment: @NetaMeta Does it work, when you run `lynx ...` on the command line?

Comment: I never run a command line so i dont really know thats why i was asking on a place to start.

Comment: @NetaMeta You might want to look into http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info and follow some of the links. Apart from that, any [bash tutorial](http://www.google.de/search?q=bash+tutorial) should do for a start. BTW, happy new year!

Comment: Thanks for help and happy new year